# Is ${\bf Set}$ a Mal'cev category?

Tags: category-theory

I read something on Mal'cev categories. It is well-known that the category of groups is an example of Mal'cev category. However, the category of sets is never given as an example of Mal'cev categories. I suppose it is not, but I have no counterexamples (or a proof if it is a Mal'cev category). Can you help me?

Comment: Incidentally, $\textbf{Set}^\textrm{op}$ is a Mal'cev category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just going from the $n$-lab's [description of a Mal'cev category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Malcev%20category)

> A Malcev category is a left exact category (= having finite limits) in which any reflexive internal relation is an equivalence relation.

it seems clear that $\underline{Set}$ cannot be a Mal'cev category. In $\underline{Set}$ an internal relation is just a relation, and reflexive and equivalence have their usual meanings. Since a set can have many reflexive relations that are not equivalences, $\underline{Set}$ cannot satisfy the condition.